# TFS Web Portal - Email alert not work

Tags: email, tfs, alert

Supporting info

Active Directory environment.
E-mail alerts are enabled on the server.
"Send Test Email" works fine from Admin Console.
There are no errors whatsoever in event viewer, including Microsoft Team Foundation Server\Debug branch.
No emails in Junk folder.
Team alerts being used are simple: "A new work item is created in this team project" (below). I tried different alerts and always ended up with the same result
Removing all members in team and keeping only one still leads to the same result.

I'm using TFS 2013.
Hope someone can help.

Comment: Create an alert for all work item changes, without the authorised as filter. Does that work?

Comment: Hi,No, I've already tried this and does not work as well